# How does one create a new Entity Framework Model by referencing an existing model?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

We would like to publish a base model, that represents our core business data.

Separate departments would reference this base model, (published as an .NET assembly)
Their project would create their schemas that reference the core business schema.

Is it possible that each team would reference this common assembly, and then build their own model on top of that with the Entity Framework (either 3.5 or 4.0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do this? [Yes](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/11/25/working-with-large-models-in-entity-framework-part-2.aspx). Should you? Well, I'll let you read the article to make your own call on that.

Comment: Thanks for the article reference.  The process sounds painful do you know if this is true for both 3.5 and 4.0?

Comment: This is certainly true for 3.5. Haven't tried it or heard anything for 4.0.

Comment: It is no easier in 4.0 than it was in 3.5